# Run an exe with command-line parameters

Tags: c#

I have an exe that I would like to use by executing it with command line parameters.

```
        var query = Path.Combine(path, calculator.ExeName + ".exe");
        var p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = query;
        //the command line parameter that causes the exe to start in an invisible mode
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "episrc"
        p.Start();
```

This code works and it starts the exe but there's one problem : the exe is supposed to be writing on a file in its directory but that doesn't happen. The process exits successfully (Exitcode0). What could be the cause of this problem?
I have a Delphi code that executes successfully the exe and the exe writes to the file but it's using the ExecProcess from win32 API thus the exe is valid and working.

Also if I try to execute it from the command prompt like so : `kowwinnt.exe episrc`  it writes to the file successfully.

Comment: Does the executable perhaps write to the directory of the calling executable?

Comment: maybe it's a matter of file/directory permissions. Try running the process as administrator: p.StartInfo.Verb="runas"

Comment: Does the process spawning this process have sufficient rights to write to said directory? Your parent process can only spawn a child process with the same rights. If your parent doesn't have the rights to write to the directory, it won't be able to finish its writing job (and you probably handle any exceptions, but that's just an assumption since there is no actual code on that part in the question)

Comment: @aevitas I don't handle any exceptions, hell I would be happy if I saw an exception cause that would help me trace the problem :D.

Comment: @Arie I haven't tried this, I will right now.

Comment: There are 2 things coming to mind. a.) Permissions for the process or the calling process  and b.) If "path" is not an absolute path then the base path will either be the path from where you are when you start your program or the path of the .exe (saw both variants already myself). As no exception is thrown it is quite probably b

Comment: @Arie no. Running like that is like kicking the chair from under your security system.

Comment: @Codor No, the application that I'm using to run the exe is located in a different directory.

Comment: Are you running this from ASP.NET? Check that the user running your application pool has permissions to write in said directory.

Comment: @CodeCaster I agree, but it's also the fastest method to check if this is the permissions problem. I mean, if it works under admininstrator and doesn't otherwise then check file permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the [Working Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Your code would look like this:

```
    var query = Path.Combine(path, calculator.ExeName + ".exe");
    var p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = query;
    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
    //the command line parameter that causes the exe to start in an invisible mode
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "episrc"
    p.Start();
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. I was totally unaware that I must set the working directory explicitly!! That issue was killing me for the last 2 days ! Thanks !!